# How can I make the program restart in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am a newbie in kivy. I made a tic tac toe game, but when one of the player wins I want the game to restart so, the players can play it again.  How can I make this in kivy or should I reset the buttons and lists that the game based on? I have tried many things like

```
self.clear_widgets()
```

but it didn't work

this is the `main.py`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import OptionProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Option():
    p1 = []
    p2 = []
    activeplayer = 1

class TicTable(BoxLayout):
    pass


class EntryButton(Button):
    opt = Option()
    obj = ObjectProperty()
    a = ObjectProperty()

    def setButton(self, p):
        self.obj.text = p
        self.obj.disabled = True


    def show_winner(self, win_player):
        if win_player:
            popup = Popup(title="There is a Winner", content=Label(text=win_player), size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 200))
            popup.open()

    def check_winner(self):
        p1_list = set(self.opt.p1)
        p2_list = set(self.opt.p2)
        winner = None
        winning = [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9},
                    {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}]
        for i in winning:
            if p1_list.intersection(i) == i:
                winner = "Player X is the Winner"
                self.show_winner(winner)
                break
            elif p2_list.intersection(i) == i:
                winner = "Player O is the Winner"
                self.show_winner(winner)
                break



    def play(self):
        if self.opt.activeplayer == 1:
            self.setButton("X")
            self.opt.p1.append(self.obj.n)
            self.check_winner()
            self.opt.activeplayer =2
        elif self.opt.activeplayer ==2:
            self.setButton("O")
            self.opt.p2.append(self.obj.n)
            self.check_winner()
            self.opt.activeplayer = 1



class TicTacToeApp(App):
    pass



if __name__ == '__main__':
    TicTacToeApp().run()
```

and this is the tictactoe.kv

```
<EntryButton>:
    obj: obj
    id: obj
    on_press: root.play()



<TicTable>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        EntryButton:
            n:1
            text: ""
        EntryButton:
            n:2
            text: ""
        EntryButton:
            n:3
            text:""
    BoxLayout:
        EntryButton:
            n:4
            text: ""
        EntryButton:
            n:5
            text: ""
        EntryButton:
            n:6
            text: ""
    BoxLayout:
        EntryButton:
            n:7
            text: ""
        EntryButton:
            n:8
            text: ""
        EntryButton:
            n:9
            text: ""




TicTable:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TicTacToeApp` should have the `build` method that returns a widget.

I will give you an example, where it is a quiz app, when the correct button is pressed (or released, in kivy lang), the app will update its quiz.

```
    import random
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.uix.label import Label

    Q_sets = ["1+1=...","1+6=...","77-43=..."];
    Opt_sets = [["2", "23"], ["4","7"], ["34","66"]];
    Ans_sets = ["2","7", "34"];

    class Option(Button):
        def __init__(self, label):
           super().__init__(self);
           self.text = label;
        def on_release(self):
           super().on_release(self);
           if self.text == self.parent.answer:
               self.parent.parent.clear_widgets();
               index = int(random.uniform(0, 3));
               New = Quiz(Q_sets[index], Opt_sets[index][0], Opt_sets[index][1], Ans_sets[index]);      
               self.parent.parent.add_widget(New);


    class Quiz(GridLayout):
        def __init__(self, question, opt1, opt2, correct):
           super().__init__(self, rows=3, cols=1);
           self.question_label = Label(text=question);
           self.opt1_button = Option(label=opt1);
           self.opt2_button = Option(label=opt2);
           self.answer=correct;
           self.add_widget(self.question_label);
           self.add_widget(self.opt1_button);
           self.add_widget(self.opt2_button);

    class QuizzesApp(App):
        def build(self):
            Container = GridLayout(); 
            Container.add_widget(Quiz(Q_sets[0], Opt_sets[0][0], Opt_sets[0][1], Ans_sets[0]));  
            return Container
```

You may study this, and then improvise for your own case. Is this okay?